# Setting cookies in an epub3 for IBooks

Tags: javascript, cookies, epub3

Does the IBooks reader allow setting and reading cookies?
Basically what I need is that the status of one page (the user clicking on some elements) gets stored and used in the next page.
I have been experimenting and so far I could not get it to work, thus I wonder whether cookies are supported at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer. I was able to store cookies inside an epub3 eBook using the [js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). Unfortunately the cookie is only visible for the current page and is not useful to share information between pages (which in epub3 are different html5 documents).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Could you use a session?

Comment: I did not search further. The solution above worked well for my purpose.